# How do I use reduce() to mimic the capabilities of forEach()?

Tags: javascript, foreach, reduce

I'm trying to accomplish a task with `reduce()` that I know how to do with `forEach()`.  Unfortunately I'm not sure how to structure the syntax and I can't find a good example.

**Example 1)** In this code I use `forEach()` to insert the word species into the first index of each array.

```js
"use strict";

var creatureArray;

creatureArray = [
  ['zombie', 30, 1, 'bite', 0, 5],
  ['skeleton', 10, 2, 'sword', 1, 10],
  ['orc', 15, 4, 'club', 1, 7]
];

creatureArray.forEach(function(value, index, array) {
  array[index].unshift('species');
});

console.log(creatureArray);
```

**Example 2)** In this code I try to accomplish something similar using `.reduce()`.  However I know that I'm missing a piece of syntax. I can't figure out how to apply the updated array to the accumulator which is then returned as an object.  Thanks so much for any help!

```js
"use strict";

var creatureArray, creatureObject;

creatureArray = [
  ['zombie', 30, 1, 'bite', 0, 5],
  ['skeleton', 10, 2, 'sword', 1, 10],
  ['orc', 15, 4, 'club', 1, 7]
];

creatureObject = creatureArray.reduce(function(accumulator, currentValue, index, array) {
  array[index].unshift('species');
  //what goes here?
  return accumulator;
}, {});

console.log(creatureObject);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how you can do accomplish it.

```js
"use strict";

var creatureArray, creatureObject;

creatureArray = [
  ['zombie', 30, 1, 'bite', 0, 5],
  ['skeleton', 10, 2, 'sword', 1, 10],
  ['orc', 15, 4, 'club', 1, 7]
];

creatureObject = creatureArray.reduce((accumulator, currentValue) => {
  return [...accumulator, ['species', ...currentValue]];
}, []);

console.log(creatureObject);
```

The `...` syntax above is called the [Spread Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator).

When applied it expands the elements of the array into the new array created by the enclosing `[` and `]`, placing each element from the old array as a top level element into the new array. This results in a flat array instead of a nested array. E.g `[[1, 2]]` -> `[[1, 2]]`, but `[...[1, 2]]` -> `[1, 2]`.
This is highly useful because it enables both simple concatenation as well as insertion of top level elements either before or after the expanded array.

Consider:

```js
"use strict";

const names = ['Linus', 'Jane', 'David'];

const withJakeAppended = [...names, 'Jake'];

const withJakePrepended = ['Jake', ...names];

[names, withJakeAppended, withJakePrepended].forEach(xs => console.log(xs));
```

As you can see, when we spread an Array it is not modified, so the pleasant syntax also enables improved ergonomics for immutable, value oriented programming.

Even better, `...` works with Sets and Maps as well. In fact, it works any [Iterable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols) object, including ones we can create ourselves.

I might add that using the fourth argument to either `Array.prototype.forEach` or `Array.prototype.forEach` is a poor practice that should be avoided.

Note if you need to do this in a browser without ES2015 support, you can write

```js
"use strict";

var creatureArray, creatureObject;

creatureArray = [
  ['zombie', 30, 1, 'bite', 0, 5],
  ['skeleton', 10, 2, 'sword', 1, 10],
  ['orc', 15, 4, 'club', 1, 7]
];

creatureObject = creatureArray.reduce(function (accumulator, currentValue) {

  return accumulator.concat([['species'].concat(currentValue)]);
}, []);

console.log(creatureObject);
```

Comment: Thanks so much!  What does this line mean?  `[...accumulator, ['species', ...currentValue]];`  It works but I don't understand it.  I want to test it all sorts of ways.

Comment: I will add a link and explanation

Comment: It looks powerful!  I can't wait to understand how that line works.

Comment: Yeah its pretty great. The next version of JS (or now if you use Babel or TypeScript) will allow you to do the same for objects which is even more awesome.

Comment: Your `Jake` example is gold!  Now I see it.

Comment: @DR01D awesome! glad that was helpful.

Answer (score 2):

[`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) is more apropriate in this case:

```js
var creatureArray = [ ['zombie'  , 30, 1, 'bite' , 0,  5],
                      ['skeleton', 10, 2, 'sword', 1, 10],
                      ['orc'     , 15, 4, 'club' , 1,  7] ]

var creatureObject = creatureArray.map(currentValue => ['species', ...currentValue] )

console.log( JSON.stringify( creatureObject ).replace(/],/g, '],\n ') )
```

Comment: That is a good way to do it.  I'm just experimenting with `reduce()`.  But it's interesting that you also used a spread operator.  I'm going to start practicing those.

Comment: @DR01D but it's not supported in IE https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator#Browser_compatibility, so concat is the safer alternative. You might also be interested in the rest parameters https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters

Comment: @Slai well yeah, that is why I included the concat example. But whether you use `[...]` or `concat`, this answer is about using  `map` instead, and it makes sense.